# Phase Difference Between Two Sine Waves With Same Frequency

Tags: matlab, vector, waveform, trigonometry, phase

I have two vectors that represent two different signals, each being a sine wave with the same frequency.  I've tried cross-correlation, Fourier transforms, Hilbert transforms, etc, but nothing returns the correct, theoretical value (in radians) at a specific frequency (should be negative).  Is there any method in Matlab to calculate the phase difference of two sine waves with the same frequency?

Note: I have access to the frequency and amplitudes of both signals, and I can post some code if needed.

Comment: All of these methods are plausible, depending on context/implementation.  What specifically did you try, what result did you get, and what result did you expect?

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth I've tried using `xcorr` (cross-correlation), the `fft` function, and the `hilbert` function in an attempt to calculate the phase difference, but the values do not match up with the theoretical values at the same frequency.  I expected values less (more negative) than what I had received.  At low frequencies, the `hilbert` transform came closest, but it jets off at higher frequencies (300+ Hz) for some reason.

Comment: Can you post some minimal runnable example including sample data, because `xcorr` and `fft` should definitely work. (I'm not familiar with `hilbert`)

Answer (score 3):

Assuming `s1` and `s2` are your isofrequential sine waves you can evaluate the phase difference (absolute value in *radians*) between them as easily as [`acos( dot(a,b) / (norm(a)*norm(b)) )`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosine_similarity).

```
x = 0:.001:100;
omega = 2*pi*100;
phi = pi/6;
s1 = sin(omega*x);
s2 = sin(omega*x - phi);
phase_diff = acos( dot(s1,s2) / (norm(s1)*norm(s2)) );
```

Comment: Just tried this in python and it works like a charm. 

I'd be interested in knowing how the wikipedia article, which is written in the context of vectors, article relates back to time series and works out to give the right answer.